# Nonlinear Second Order Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been trying to solve the following ODE and cannot get anywhere with it:

$\frac {d^{2}y}{dx^{2}} = 1-( \frac {dy}{dx})^{2}$.

The techniques I have used which are really the techniques for simple 2nd order ODEs don't work at all. Using the "D" operator doesn't work.

I am aware that I could write the RHS as
$(1-dy/dx)(1+dy/dx)$
but it seems that doesn't get me very far.
I am also aware I could try to solve this using infinite series, i.e
$y = a_{0}+a_{1}x+... $
and do tedious calculations to get somewhat of an answer, but I am hoping for a closed form answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

(BTW this is not, strictly speaking, homework, just a puzzle I've been thinking about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $dy/dx=u$. Then the equation becomes
$$
u'=1-u^2,
$$
which is a first order ODE that can be solved by separation of variables.

Comment: Wow. So simple. I feel stupid.